# CloudEndure Finalized Initial Sync Stuck in Data Replication Progress

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, migration, cloud

I'm pleading to all CloudEndure experts out there. We are having this issue at the last step of CloudEndure replication. I have created a test instance in the same subnet and the same security group with the Replication server and have checked everything AWS suggests. The test instance connects to EC2 APIs in the region, it connects to console.cloudendure.com, CloudEndure agent seems to be working on the source machine. I even created a VPC Endpoint to ensure EC2 API access through AWS network. I might go crazy over this. What could be the issue?

The troubleshooting guide I used can be found in AWS Support with the headline: "Why is my CloudEndure replication process stuck at 100% with the "Finalizing Initial Sync" message appearing in the console?"

Comment: Could you please clarify in which way your question related to Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: can you share the job progress logs